# seamless join PNGs one above the other

Tags: bash, image, terminal, imagemagick, image-editing

How can I use ImageMagick (probably the `montage` command) to join png images into a new png, where each of the input pngs becomes a part of the final one? All vertically arranged?

Like so:

[image]

2 pngs of roughly equal width (±2px) and different heights joined on top of one another seamlessly.

I don't really mind so much what happens to excess/smaller widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
convert 1.png 2.png -append result.png
```

- To align left edges, add `-gravity West`.
- To align right edges, add `-gravity East`.
- To align centres, add `-gravity center`.

To add a transparent spacer between:

```
convert -background none 1.png -size 10x10 xc:none 2.png -append result.png
```

Oh, you've gone horizontal! Change `-append` to `+append`.

Answer (score 0):

this one:

```
convert -append img1.png img2.png out.png
```

e.g. from

[image]

[image]

will get

[image]

And the:

```
convert +append img1.png img2.png out2.png
```

will produce

[image]